# Unexpected `;` when trying to trim extra endlines

Tags: ruby, erb

I'm learning how to use `erb` (and ruby for that matter) and having a hard time replicating examples from [this](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_template_erb.html) site where the authors demonstrate that you can remove the trailing endline by closing a block with `-%>` but when I do this I get a syntax error

`syntax error, unexpected ';' (Syntax Error); @values.each do |val| -; _erbout.<< "\\n".freeze`

Here's an example of my code that doesn't run

```
<% @values = ['one','two']; puts "Was assigned."%>
<% @values.each do |val| -%>
Some stuff with <%= val %>
<% end -%>
```

But the following runs

```
<% @values = ['one','two']; puts "Was assigned."%>
<% @values.each do |val| %>
Some stuff with <%= val %>
<% end %>
```

---

#### Final Solution

Just to add to the accepted answer, I was running erb from the command line with

`erb test.cfg.erb`

Reading `man erb` you can enable newline trimming by setting `-T` with the option `-` so

`erb -T - test.cfg.erb`

Is the command I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check out the [ERB class doc](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html), you'll see there's an optional `trim_mode` keyword argument in `ERB.new`, and one of its possible values is:

```
-  omit blank lines ending in -%>
```

By default, the `-%>` elements are just considered invalid.

Now if you compile your first template giving it the correct `trim_mode` option:

```rb
str = %q(
<% @values = ['one','two']; puts "Was assigned."%>
<% @values.each do |val| -%>
Some stuff with <%= val %>
<% end -%>
)

erb = ERB.new(str, trim_mode: '-')  # Without trim_mode you'll get the error
puts erb.result(binding)
```

You'll get the correct result:

```
Was assigned.


Some stuff with one
Some stuff with two
```

The guide you've linked to is from *Puppet*, and presumably they use `ERB` internally for templating and always pass it the `trim_mode: '-'` option. But if you're using `ERB` directly, you have to remember to include it yourself.